# Find the matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a matrix such that $A\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 4 \\6 \end{bmatrix}$, where $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, where $c$ and ?$d$ are some scalars. Find $A$.

First, I rewrote $\vec{x}$ as $$\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}2 + c + 2d \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then I wrote the equations \begin{align}
a_{11}(2+c+2d)+a_{12}c+a_{13}d &= 0 \\
2a_{11}+(a_{11}+a_{12})c+(2a_{11}+a_{13})d&=0 \\ 2\vec{a_1}+(\vec{a)1}+\vec{a_2})c+(2\vec{a)1}+\vec{a_3})d &= \vec{0} \\ (2+c+2d)\vec{a_1}+c\vec{a_2}+d\vec{a_3}&=\vec{0}
\end{align}

Where can I go from here? I thought of transformations but I do not know if that is the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: Is that relation true for any $c,d$?

Comment: Yes, it is for any c and d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely determine a matrix, we only need to know its values on the elements of a basis. Since we know that:
$$A\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}2-2\cdot 1 \\ 0-2\cdot 1 \\ 0-2\cdot 0 \end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}2-2 \\ 0-0\\ 0-1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\4 \\6\end{bmatrix}$$

By using $(c=d=0)$, $(c=-2,d=0)$ and $(c=0,d=-1)$ respectively.

Then 
$$A\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -2\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ -1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\4 \\6\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{align}
A\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} \\
A\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\- 2 \\ -3\end{bmatrix} \\
A\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ -4 \\ -6\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

So: $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 &-1  &-2\\ 2 &-2 &-4\\ 3 &-3 &-6\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: +1. Good answer,but I think it needs a little clarification for the beginner. Explain how in the first step, you're reducing the column vectors of x to linear combinations of the column forms of standard basis vectors of $R^3$. I think this will make the answer even better.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Sorry, but I don't feel motivated enough to do it this time. :( I guess this answer will have to do.